# Get status ID's using Twitterizer2

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

I am currently writing an application that is posting Tweets to my Twitter timeline using [Twitterizer](https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer).

However I would also like to have the option to delete multiple Tweets.

I have managed to delete individual Tweets by manually retrieving the statusID's of from the site then hard coding them into my method, as shown below.

```
int statusID = 12345; //retrieved from the individual Tweet online    

TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> tweetResponse = TwitterStatus.Delete(tokens, statusID);
if (tweetResponse.Result == RequestResult.Success)
{

     MessageBox.Show(tweetResponse.Result.ToString());

}
```

Is it possible to retrive a list of statusID's that this method could loop over and for each exisiting ID, delete that comment?

Also, is it possible to add Geo coordinates when updating a status using Twitterizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a code that allows you to loop through the ID's. In this case it is using TwitterFriendShip Class, but It should be the same using the other tweet classes:

```
friendCol = TwitterFriendship.FriendsIds(tokens, options);

Cursor = friendCol.ResponseObject.NextCursor;

foreach (int usuario in friendCol.ResponseObject)
{
 usuarios newUser = new usuarios();  
 newUser.userId = usuario;
 FollowingList.Add(newUser);
 }


for (int i = 0; i < FollowingList.Count -1; i++)
{

 //Delete by userID

 TwitterResponse<TwitterUser> ans=   TwitterFriendship.Delete(tokens, FollowingList[i].userId);

}
```

Try this, to get the tweets in timeline and delete them using the id;

**EDIT:**

```
TwitterStatusCollection staCol = TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(tokens).ResponseObject;

foreach (TwitterStatus status in staCol)
{
  status.Delete(tokens);
}
```

NOTE: The TwitterStatus Class has ID and StringID properties

Comment: This has the 'FriendsIds' option however is there a 'StatusIds' option? I cant find anything.